# Проставление реакции к сообщению

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Постигаю все прелести создания собственного бота. Возникла следующая трудность с добавление реакции к сообщению.

Есть:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
nbr = [' :ok:  - ок\n :ballot_box_with_check: - чек']
```

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['тест'])
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        embed=discord.Embed(
            title='Тест!',
            description=''.join(nbr)
            )
    )
```

Уже как только не пробовал, но не могу понять, каким образом мне добавить к появляющемуся сообщению реакцию от бота, чтобы по ним уже могли нажимать другие люди.

Реакции :ok: и :ballot_box_with_check:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите добавить реакцию, то вот:

```py
@bot.command(aliases = ['тест'])
async def test(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send(
        embed=discord.Embed(
            title='Тест!',
            description=''.join(nbr)
            )
    )
    await msg.reaction_add('реакция')
    await msg.reaction_add('реакция')
```

Вы должны просто к отправленному сообщение (присвоить переменную) добавить реакцию `await переменная.reaction_add('реакция')`

Answer (score 1):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
token = 'ВАШ ТОКЕН'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'грустно' in message.content.lower():
        embed = discord.Embed(title='как жаль')
        message = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        await message.add_reaction('☹') #Add a reaction to the message
bot.run(token)
```

Вот простенький бот, который отвечает на сообщение, в котором есть слово грустно, и ставит грустную реакцию. Вот так:

[image: Бот]

Вместо **☹** можно поставить любой эмодзи, скопировав [отсюда](https://www.emojilo.com/ru/). Не беспокойтесь, если в коде эмодзи заменятся **пробелом**, **[]** или **?** - Python "заберёт" и восстановит их.
Кстати, если не хотите заходить на сайт, вот смайлики, которые вам нужны:  и